# Overloaded Addition assignment operator in C++ for two /more than two objects?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have overloaded the + operator like this

```
class sample
{
private : 
  int x;
public :
  sample(int x1 =0)
  {
    x = x1;
  }

  sample operator+(sample s);
};

sample sample::operator+(sample s)
{
  x = x + s.x;
  return *this;
}

int  main()
{
  sample s1(10);
  sample s2;
  s2 = s2 + s1;
  return 0;    
}
```

Is this correct?
My question is If I want to add two different sample objects how will I overloaded the opeartor; e.g for `s = s1 + s2`;

I feel like doing `s = s + s1 + s2` with the existing implementation.

Comment: Look here! http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html  or here  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html

Comment: note that `operator+` should _not_ change the value of the object on the left of the `+`, but yours does.  If you wrote `s3 = s1 + s2`, your code would change `s1` to also hold the result.

Comment: Also, `main` has a `int` return type.

Comment: Also, you seem to be attempting to make the `operator+` a member function of the `sample` class, but you've done that completely wrong, this code [doesn't even come close to compiling](http://ideone.com/H7HjK).  See http://sscce.org for how to write code for a question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using friend operator overload should do the trick for you and is a common way to define binary operators, just add:

```
friend sample operator+(const sample& a, const sample& b); //in class

sample operator+(const sample& a, const sample& b) { //outside the class
    return sample(a.x + b.x);
}
```

If you want it to remain a member, (which has downsides in some rare scenarios, and no upsides), you have to make the operator a `const` function:

```
sample operator+(sample s) const; //in class

sample sample::operator+(const sample& b) const { //outside the class
    return sample(this->x + b.x);
}
```

Either of these will allow operator chaining.  The reason your previous `s = s + s1 + s2` was failing, is that the `s + s1` would execute and return a *temporary* `sample` object.  Then, it would attempt to add `s2` to that sample.  However, temporaries can only be `const` references<sup>[1]</sup>, and as such, can only use `const` member functions.  Since your `operator+` member function is not a `const` function, you cannot use that function on the `const` temporary.  Note that to make it `const`, I had to rewrite it, since your version modifies the object on the left side of the `+`.

<sup>[1]with exceptions aren't particularly relevant here, namely rvalues</sup>

Comment: it looks Ok.Is it the only way to perfrom this using the friend.?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question, are you asking if using the `friend` keyword is the only way to achieve the requirement?

Comment: i meant without using friend function can this be done.But I think this is the only way.

Comment: @softy: no, you can do it without `friend` functions just as easily, but your code is wrong, and this is the "normal" way to do it

Comment: Yes you can do it without friend, but to do that you have to add a getter method for the `x` member variable

Comment: @h3nr1x: ...or you simply make it a member function properly.  (In this case, it needs to be a `const` function)

Comment: @softy: It's not really "different" enough from h3nr1x's answer, so I simply added it to his, with a full description of why.