# Overloaded operator as argument of copy constructor

Tags: c++

I want to use copy constructor with the result of my overloaded `operator*`. I found the way to do this: by returning reference from the operator. What I would like to know:

1. Is this okay?

Here is the example:

```
class Foo{
    public:
        double x,y,z;
        Foo() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {};
        Foo(double xi, double yi, double zi) : x(xi), y(yi), z(zi) {};
        Foo(const Foo &bar) : x(bar.x), y(bar.y), z(bar.z) {};
};

Foo& operator * (const double &b, Foo &a){ // Yep, I want to modify a
    a.x *= b;
    a.y *= b;
    a.z *= b;
    return a;
}

int main(){
    Foo temp;
    Foo bar = 4*temp; // Here is what I want to do!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `int b = 4*4;`, do you expect the second `4` to become 16? This is what your operator does.

Comment: Why can't you return a plain `Foo` from it? I don't see why it wouldn't work. Why your operator modifies the `Foo` passed to it, instead of creating and returning a temporary?

Comment: @O'Neil Yep, you are right. It's different things. But I expect this in mine example

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I need to modify it

Comment: No, you need to create a new one, and let the two parameters unmodified

Comment: What O'Neil said. Why do you think you need to modify it?

Comment: Implement `operator *=` to modify it.

Comment: @O'Neil I need an operator, that will change Foo object. I want to be able to write something like 'temp*4;'

Comment: @Constructovec In the question you use `Foo bar = 4*temp;` instead. Is it not sufficient that this works (i.e. is it not sufficient that `bar` gets the value `4*temp`)? Why must `temp` be modified?

Comment: Then, as @tkausl said, implement `operator *=` and use it as `temp *= 4;`.

Comment: Yep, think *= is more clear, but still I need to return a referrence

Comment: _Why_ do you need to return a reference?

Comment: And you are allowed to do so with `operator *=`.

Comment: @tkausl 'Foo bar(4*=temp);' throw error 'Could not find a match for "Foo::Foo(void)"
' otherwise

Comment: @Constructovec - for that to work it is necessary to DEFINE `operator*=()`.   That doesn't happen by magic, and is not done in the OP's code.

Comment: @Peter Yep, I know that. I have defined it in mine code and checked this before. Anyway it wasn't suppose to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `operator *`, we expect:

- the two inputs **to remain unmodified**,
- a **new** object to be returned (by value).

which gives us the following signature:

```
Foo operator * (double a, Foo const & b);
```

If you want to modifiy `temp` = `4*temp`, use `operator *=` as `temp *= 4;` instead, which modifies `temp` and returns its reference:

```
Foo & operator *= (Foo & a, double b) {
    a.x *= b;
    a.y *= b;
    a.z *= b;
    return a;
}
```

**<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bfdfd03c6bf95d6)</kbd>**

Comment: Yep, we excpect this usually. But here is I have deal with vectors, on which this operation have different, from for example integers, effect.

Sorry, I made my question unclear not determining this moment.

Comment: @Constructovec We expect this behavior no matter the type is. Vector included.

Comment: Sorry, my english is very gud :) I have edited mine question.

Comment: So when I program something, it's good to make the behavior of mine programs so similar to the generally accepted behavior ( of alike programs) as it possible?

Comment: You said that mine operator's behavior is unexpected. I wonder: it's better to try to make everything traditional ( expectable )?

Comment: Sure, yes. Or users will have have trouble using your code, and waste time on finding why they don't get the result they expect.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do so. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
const Foo operator *(const double& b, Foo& a)
{
    a.x *= b;
    a.y *= b;
    a.z *= b;

     return a;
}
```

might be what you want, if you really want `a` to be modified. I would personally drop the reference. The `const` on the return type is necessary to make sure something like:

```
Foo a, c;
double b = 1.0;

(a * b) = c;
```

does not become legal.

Your approach is not the *standard* way to do things. Usually, you will have:

```
const Foo operator *(const double& b, const Foo& a)
{
    return Foo(a.x *b, a.y * b, a.z * b);
}
```

Which a standard, commutative multiplication in which the operands are left unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Just to make clear. I'm implementing 3D vector, so always when I type 'vector*3;' vector should be modified.

Comment: When you have `int`s and you write `int a = 3 * b`, `b` is not modified. The value you want is now in `a`. It seems to be the same here, if you want to have it the standard way.

Comment: Ok, if you don't need it to be standard, I would suggest you edit your question to remove it.

Comment: So for what you want your approach is OK, minus the reference (it is legal C++ and does what you want), but I would add a `const` to the return type.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Is this okay?

It's well formed, and behaviour is well defined. However, it is very unconventional as binary arithmetic operator typically does not modify its operands. This will be very confusing to users of the code.

Compared to the usual way to define the binary arithmetic operators, your approach is also more limiting:

```
Foo get_foo();         // for exposition
Foo bar = 4*get_foo(); // oops, this doesn't work
```

Given the unconventionality, the demonstrated limitation, and the lack of benefits compared to the conventional approach, I would say that it's *not okay*.

> 2 Do standard operators use a similar approach? For example:
>
> ```
> int b = 4*4;
> ```

No. None of the built-in binary arithmetic operators behave this way. None of the overloads in the standard library behave this way either (I didn't check, but I'm confident anyway).

---

I recommend doing the usual way, especially considering that this is for a 3d vector:

```
A operator*(const B& lhs, const A& rhs);
```

The operands are const references, so they will not be modified, and the result is a new instance that can be used to initialize a variable.

---

PS. Your custom copy constructor does nothing more than the implicit copy constructor does, so it appears to be redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I should wrote it at the beggining: I'm implementing 3D vector, so always when I type 'vector*3;' vector should be modified.

Comment: @Constructovec why do you think that `vector` should be modified by that expression? That's not how a programmer would expect 3d vectors to behave. I recommend that `vector` should not be modified by that expression.

Comment: But what else can happen? I mean what else can do multiplying vector on number?

Comment: @Constructovec *"What else can happen"* -> The function can return the result of the multiplication. That is how the built-in operators work and that is how all of the overloads in the standard library work. *"what else can do multiplying vector on number? "* -> I don't understand your question.

Comment: What is the result of multiplying geometric vector on number?

Comment: "This will be very confusing to users of the code." Very important IMO.

Comment: @Constructovec Intuitively, I'd say that the result of multiplying a geometric vector by a number would be a new geometric vector, whose each dimension is the product of the corresponding dimension of the vector operand, and the number operand.

Comment: @user2079303 Yep, I think 'operator*=' makes this operation more clear

Comment: @Constructovec Pretty good performance. I didn't notice any slowdown.

Comment: @user2079303 Okay. Thanks for your help!